# Remove class,id attributes of all tags in given html posted

Tags: html, asp.net, regex

I have a fck editor in which the user enters some text. And in the code i want to strip the class,id attributes of the text posted. I know this can be done through regular expressions
And i have written some code to do so but unfortunately it's not working.

```
private string RemoveScripts(string input)
{
  string re1 = "(.*?";  // Non-greedy match on filler
  string re2 = "(class)";   // Word 1
  string re3 = "(=)";   // Any Single Character 1
  string re4 = "(\".*?\"))";    // Double Quote String 1
  string re5 = "(id)";
  Regex regClass = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
  Regex regID = new Regex(re1 + re5 + re3 + re4, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

  input = regClass.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceClassID));
  input = regID.Replace(input, new MatchEvaluator(ReplaceID));
  return input;
}

private string ReplaceClassID(Match m)
{ return ""; }
```

Comment: Actually, I'm *not* sure this can be done with regular expressions.  "Real" regular expressions aren't powerful enough to parse all of HTML.  Now, pretty much everything these days is an extended regular expression, and what you're trying to parse doesn't *sound* like it will run afoul of the recursive nature of HTML (which is what regular expressions can't deal with), but in the *best* case, it'll be terribly complicated (thanks to comments, CDATA blocks, and the like).  Your best bet is to use a real HTML parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
classPattern = "class=[',\"]([\w- ])*[',\"]"
idPattern = "id=[',\"]([\w- ])*[',\"]"
```